How do I access multiple BloCs from a single component in Flutter Flame?
I am building a Flutter Flame game and am trying to have a single action add events to two different blocs. For example, when the character picks up an item I want it to go into an InventoryBloc and increment a counter in GameStatsBloc (for total lifetime items collected).
The documentation examples show things like (copied from here):
class Player extends PositionComponent
    with FlameBlocListenable<PlayerInventoryBloc, PlayerInventoryState> {

  @override
  void onNewState(state) {
    updateGear(state);
  }
}

but explicitly states that you can't use multiple blocs that way. Similarly, if I try to use multiple FlameBlocListeners they don't provide access to the relevant blocs to add events (they are listeners after all).
Is there a clean way to have a single component interact with multiple blocs? The only way I can think of doing it is making a dummy parent component that uses FlameBlocListenable<InventoryBloc, InventoryState> that passes the bloc to a child that uses FlameBlocListenable<GameStatsBloc, GameStatsState>, e.g.:
class InventoryProviderComponent extends Component with FlameBlocListenable<InventoryBloc, InventoryState> {
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    add(Player(inventoryBloc: bloc));
  }
}

class Player extends PositionComponent with FlameBlocListenable<GameStatsBloc, GameStatsState> {
  Player({required this.inventoryBloc});
  final InventoryBloc inventoryBloc;
  ...
  // Can now interact with bloc and inventoryBloc as needed to add events
}

This feels pretty awkward to me and would become increasingly cumbersome if more blocs were needed (though that might indicate other issues with the structure of the code).

Your problem reminds me at Mediator (design pattern)
I recommend you to create an intermediary class, like GameBlocMediator, to handle interactions with BLoCs. Also, since you don't have access to the BuildContext in onLoad, use the GetIt package for dependency injection.
class GameBlocMediator {
  final InventoryBloc inventoryBloc;
  final GameStatsBloc gameStatsBloc;

  GameBlocMediator({
    required this.inventoryBloc,
    required this.gameStatsBloc,
  });

  void onItemPickedUp(Item item) {
    inventoryBloc.add(AddItemEvent(item)); 
    gameStatsBloc.add(IncrementCounterEvent()); 
  }
}

Create a file like services_locator.dart
final GetIt getIt = GetIt.instance;

void setupServiceLocator() {
  getIt.registerLazySingleton<InventoryBloc>(() => InventoryBloc());
  getIt.registerLazySingleton<GameStatsBloc>(() => GameStatsBloc());
  getIt.registerLazySingleton<GameBlocMediator>(() => GameBlocMediator(
        inventoryBloc: getIt<InventoryBloc>(),
        gameStatsBloc: getIt<GameStatsBloc>(),
      ));
}

Initialize GetIt in main.dart
void main() {
  setupServiceLocator();
...
  runApp(...);
}

You can inject your Mediator in your Player Component
class Player extends PositionComponent {
  final GameBlocMediator mediator = getIt<GameBlocMediator>();

  void pickUpItem(Item item) {
    mediator.onItemPickedUp(item);
  }
}


Right, this makes sense but the issue is that in onLoad in a Flame Component you don't have access to context. Otherwise I could just do the reads you have directly without needing a helper class. On some level BLoCs are already a "Mediator" of sorts as they are the single source of truth for the application's state.

In your case, you can use dependency injection with the GetIt package.
This will allow you to retrieve your BloCs globally without needing the context.
I updated my reponse
